# Tweener fade with alpha

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

I'm having troubles with getting my textfield to fade from alpha 0 to alpha 1 with Tweener.
Everything else works fine, so I suspect it has something to do with applying my textformats on the textfield?

This is my code

private function swapText(e:Event):void {

```
        applyTextFormats();
        addChild(_textContainer);
        var textfromx:int = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].textfromx;
        var textfromy:int = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].textfromy;
        var textendx:int = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].textendx;
        var textendy:int = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].textendy;

        _textTimer.stop();

        var texteffectDuration:uint = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].texteffectduration;           
        var texteffectType:int  = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].texteffecttype;


        _effectDelay = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].effectdelay;

        if(texteffectType == 1) {

            _textContainer.x = textfromx;
            _textContainer.y = textfromy;
            Tweener.addTween(_textContainer, { x:textendx, y:textendy, time:texteffectDuration, onComplete:function() { _slideTimer.start(); } } );
        } 
        else {

            _textContainer.alpha = 0;
            _textContainer.x = textendx;
            _textContainer.y = textendy;
            Tweener.addTween(_textContainer, { alpha:1, time:texteffectDuration, onComplete:function() { _slideTimer.start(); } } );
        }
    }

    private function applyTextFormats():void {

        _textContainer.text = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].imgtext; 
        _textContainer.width = _imgWidth;
        _textContainer.height = 40;
        _formatsText.size = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].fontsize;
        _formatsText.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        _formatsText.color = _xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].fontcolor;
        _formatsText.font = _xmlData.@fontface;
        if (_xmlData.image[_currentActiveSlide].fontbold == 1) {

            _formatsText.bold = true;
        }
        else { _formatsText.bold = false; }
        _textContainer.setTextFormat(_formatsText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are embeding the fonts properly and to set textField.embedFont=true.